# Can't get Bootstrap glyphicons to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, glyphicons

Both bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css are loaded and this is what my code looks like:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
```

It doesn't give me any errors. I also have this code in a jquery-ui-tab. Maybe thats the problem?

My head-tag:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    body 
    {
        padding-top: 40px;}

        .container
        {
            margin-left:2px;
        }
        .actions
        {
            background:none;
            border-top:none;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: I hope you have included the appropriate .css or .js files in your head tag. Show us the html.

Comment: @AmarDuplantier the bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css both have been loaded in the browser.

Comment: Check in Chrome DevTools if you are getting any error..

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.3.2, compared to Bootstrap 3, many things have changed, including icons.  In 3, your code seems ok.  However, if you are using 2.3.2, the format should be something like this:

```
<button><i class="icon-pencil" /><button>
```

Good luck!